# Search for the most recent excel file in in a subfolder for which the title contains a specific text with Python

Tags: python

I've only just recently starting to code with Python and I found my first problem which I can't seem to figure out after days of research. Hopefully someone on this forum can help me out.

**The situation:** In our company I have multiple folders and subfolders. Within those subfolders I we have excel files called:

- Item Supply Demand "date".xlsx
- Backorder report"date".xlsx
- Product available report"date".xlsx

Everyday in the morning our IT downloads a new file with these names and the date of today. For example today it will look like this: Item Supply Demand 23-06-22.xlsx

**The goal:** I want to find the most recent Excel file within our subfolders which contains the name "Item Supply Demand". I already know how to find the most recent Excel file with the glob.glob function. However, I cannot seem to add an extra filter on a name part. Below the code that I already have:

```
import sys
import csv
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os.path
import pathlib
import re

#search for all Excel files
files = glob.glob(r"Pathname\**\*.xlsx", recursive = True)

#find most recent Item Supply Demand report
text_files = str(files)
if 'Item Supply Demand' in text_files:
max_file = max(files, key=os.path.getctime)

#Add the file to the dataframe 
df = pd.read_excel(max_file)

df
```

Does anyone know what is currently missing or wrong on my code?

Many thanks in advance for helping our!

Cheer,
Kav

Comment: ugh, comment won't replicate... will answer

Comment: Wow you are amazing! Thanks alot, I was so close already. This worked like a charm :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, your already 99% of the way there.

```
files = glob.glob(r"Pathname\**\*Item Supply Demand*.xlsx", recursive = True)
```

Then I suppose the code block underneath can drop the conditional to become

```
# find most recent Item Supply Demand report
max_file = max(files, key=os.path.getctime)
```

<strike>Note - I haven't checked will that syntax do what you want - or even work at all - I'm assuming its working for you as its not the focus of your question.</strike>

edit: Just checked that - nice - it will give you exactly what you want.

Comment: ^This is cleaner. However, if statement needs to be modified. Edited my answer related to to it.

Answer (score 0):

The variable "files" is already list of strings. You can create list of string that match only the substring, then use that list.

```
wanted_file_substring = "Item Supply Demand"
matching_files = [specific_file for specific_file in files if wanted_file_substring in specific_file]
max_file = max(matching_files, key=os.path.getctime)
```

Edit my answer:
Either answer you choose, you need to initialize variable outside of "if" statement or move the read_excel line into the if statement. If the file you want is not found, your program will error out, because pandas is trying to reference a variable that doesn't exist.

Change the if statement to:

```
 if files:
    max_file = max(.....)
    pd.read_excel(max_file)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I will go with the first solution of AmigaNicolaskn since that one worked :).